# dplyr: filter where two columns in data.frame are equal

Tags: r, dplyr

In base R one can easily filter to rows where two columns are equals like so:

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl==mtcars$carb,]
```

Using `dplyr`'s `filter` this can be done easily

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl==carb)
```

But if I am writing a function using this code I would want to use `filter_`, but this code doesn't work

```
mtcars %>% filter_("cyl"=="carb")
```

Since in this case it thinks "carb" is a value to test rather than a variable.

My question is how can you use `filter_` to compare two variables in a data.frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the whole thing in quotes:

```
mtcars %>% filter_("cyl==carb")
```

Or, as effel has already suggested, this will also work:

```
mtcars %>% filter_(~cyl==carb)
```

Comment: I think the point is to help with a function `f <- function(col1, col2) mtcars %>% filter_(paste0(col1,"==", col2))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune right, or `paste(col1,col2, sep="==")`

Answer (score 5):

There's more on this [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

> It’s best to use a formula, because a formula captures both the
>   expression to evaluate, and the environment in which it should be a
>   evaluated. This is important if the expression is a mixture of
>   variables in the data frame and objects in the local environment

```
library(dplyr)

airquality %>%
  filter_(~Month == Day)
airquality %>% filter_(~Month == Day)
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 2    NA     264 14.3   79     6   6
# 3    77     276  5.1   88     7   7
# 4    89     229 10.3   90     8   8
# 5    21     230 10.9   75     9   9
```

Alternatively:

> There are three ways to quote inputs that dplyr understands:
>   With a formula, `~ mean(mpg)`. With `quote()`, `quote(mean(mpg))`. As a string: `"mean(mpg)"`.